# Vega Zoomable USA Map

Tags: vega

I want to use this map https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/zoomable-world-map/ but only for USA.

I used this spec.

```
  private specVega = {
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
    "description": "An interactive world map supporting pan and zoom.",
    "width": 900,
    "height": 500,
    "autosize": "none",

    "signals": [
      { "name": "tx", "update": "width / 2" },
      { "name": "ty", "update": "height / 2" },
      {
        "name": "scale",
        "value": 150,
        "on": [{
          "events": {"type": "wheel", "consume": true},
          "update": "clamp(scale * pow(1.0005, -event.deltaY * pow(16, event.deltaMode)), 150, 3000)"
        }]
      },
      {
        "name": "angles",
        "value": [0, 0],
        "on": [{
          "events": "mousedown",
          "update": "[rotateX, centerY]"
        }]
      },
      {
        "name": "cloned",
        "value": null,
        "on": [{
          "events": "mousedown",
          "update": "copy('projection')"
        }]
      },
      {
        "name": "start",
        "value": null,
        "on": [{
          "events": "mousedown",
          "update": "invert(cloned, xy())"
        }]
      },
      {
        "name": "drag", "value": null,
        "on": [{
          "events": "[mousedown, window:mouseup] > window:mousemove",
          "update": "invert(cloned, xy())"
        }]
      },
      {
        "name": "delta", "value": null,
        "on": [{
          "events": {"signal": "drag"},
          "update": "[drag[0] - start[0], start[1] - drag[1]]"
        }]
      },
      {
        "name": "rotateX", "value": 0,
        "on": [{
          "events": {"signal": "delta"},
          "update": "angles[0] + delta[0]"
        }]
      },
      {
        "name": "centerY", "value": 0,
        "on": [{
          "events": {"signal": "delta"},
          "update": "clamp(angles[1] + delta[1], -60, 60)"
        }]
      }
    ],

    "projections": [
      {
        "name": "projection",
        "type": "mercator",
        "scale": {"signal": "scale"},
        "rotate": [{"signal": "rotateX"}, 0, 0],
        "center": [0, {"signal": "centerY"}],
        "translate": [{"signal": "tx"}, {"signal": "ty"}]
      }
    ],

    "data": [
      {
        "name": "counties",
        values: null,
        "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "states"},
      },
      {
        "name": "graticule",
        "transform": [
          { "type": "graticule", "step": [15, 15] }
        ]
      }
    ],

    "marks": [
      {
        "type": "shape",
        "from": {"data": "graticule"},
        "encode": {
          "enter": {
            "strokeWidth": {"value": 1},
            "stroke": {"value": "#ddd"},
            "fill": {"value": null}
          }
        },
        "transform": [
          { "type": "geoshape", "projection": "projection" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "shape",
        "from": {"data": "states"},
        "encode": {
          "enter": {
            "strokeWidth": {"value": 0.5},
            "stroke": {"value": "#bbb"},
            "fill": {"value": "#e5e8d3"}
          }
        },
        "transform": [
          { "type": "geoshape", "projection": "projection" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

this.specVega["data"][0]["values"] = "data/us-10m.json" (this is just for understanding which data i used)

So i put data for only US here, but it didn't work. Got an error in console:

```
Undefined data set name: "states"
```

In general i just need a zoomable map for USA only, which i am going to use as a bubble map.
If this map has a zoom i would definitely use it https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/geo_layer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an working example of USA map by states or counties in "albersUsa" projection. Zooming is by mouse wheel and panning by mouse click-drag. For better performance, zooming and panning are best done with states instead of counties.

[View in Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-VDLRbfEDOWSgrXQ5UACig9T+OHTIpG936zpmOgAVN4humZZR5QIpDoALTeuAGSjyeoggCaZYrkSrADZ683W+2QTc2PIAJST+uGlI6C3JaefRnfX4xynpHq9Za+CDZwy9M4BhELTrNM3ZKQAJmyzMTOGThjKzSzObzW6Bu6jB7gvWzVJHgGzSJIyOgANSOJ+orQhAf6jkgQEgcyjYAMw5DoMrXku9Zvggub5t++6gv+PKYEhMpgZB+YILB8H4iCFEoQ22HzgAHEujJuuuwrQTu2rEYeAHkcep5Iuel4pLeoHuhorQgMOmBkvJgbBmUtEMHBshDJIHz3kmKZdHxRG-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-uB1iIfoKT4eU+DMfiHH0MKQYRh12nmfZzAJfpagiSUAIBep8XucfxAGXJgICkYcxoPUOmADJrlzgAIOAbFZCoUnjIae3NLZqWtuTQ+ERvpr1ehoY0W8frr13q7D4QA)

[image: Vega USA map in "albersUsa" projection with mouse zoom and pan]

```
{
"$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
"description": "An interactive USA map supporting pan and zoom.",
"width": 900,
"height": 500,
"autosize": "none",

"signals": [

  {
    "name": "signal_show_map_graticule", 
    "value": true,
    "bind": {
        "input": "checkbox",
         "name": "Map graticule: "}
  },

  {
    "name": "signal_states_or_counties", 
    "value": "states",
    "bind": { "input": "select", 
              "options": ["states", "counties"],
              "name": "Map areas: "
    }
  },

  {
    "name": "signal_map_scale",
    "value": 1000,
    "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 1000, "max": 4000, "step": 50, "name": "Map scale: "},
    "on": [{
      "events": {"type": "wheel", "consume": true},
      "update": "round(clamp(signal_map_scale * pow(1.0005, -event.deltaY * pow(16, event.deltaMode)), 1000, 4000))"
    }]
  },

  { "name": "signal_translate_xy", 
  "value": [450, 250],
  "update": "[clamp(signal_translate_last_xy[0] + signal_mouse_delta_xy[0], -300, 1200), clamp(signal_translate_last_xy[1] + signal_mouse_delta_xy[1], -200, 800)]"
  },

  { "name": "signal_translate_last_xy", 
    "value": [450, 250],
    "on": [{
      "events": [
        {"type": "mousedown"}
      ],
      "update": "signal_translate_xy"
    }]
  },

  {
    "name": "signal_mouse_start_xy",
    "value": [0, 0],
    "on": [{
      "events": [
        {"type": "mousedown"}
      ],
      "update": "xy()"
    }]
  },

  {
    "name": "signal_mouse_drag_xy", 
    "value": [0, 0],
    "on": [{
      "events": [
        {
          "type": "mousemove",
          "between": [
            {"type": "mousedown"},
            {"type": "mouseup"}
          ]
        }
      ], 
      "update": "xy()"
    }]
  },

  {
    "name": "signal_mouse_delta_xy", 
    "value": [0, 0],
    "update": "[signal_mouse_drag_xy[0] - signal_mouse_start_xy[0], signal_mouse_drag_xy[1] - signal_mouse_start_xy[1]]"
  }
],

"projections": [
  {
    "name": "map_projection",
    "type": "albersUsa",
    "scale": {"signal": "signal_map_scale"},

    
    "translate": {"signal": "signal_translate_xy"}
  }
],

"data": [
  {
    "name": "data_geo_usa",
    "url": "data/us-10m.json",
    "format": {
        "type": "topojson", 
        "feature": {"signal": "signal_states_or_counties"}
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "data_geo_graticule",
    "transform": [
      { "type": "graticule", "step": [5, 5] }
    ]
  }
],

"marks": [
  {
    "type": "shape",
    "from": {"data": "data_geo_graticule"},
    "encode": {
      "enter": {
        "strokeWidth": {"value": 1},
        "stroke": {"value": "#ddd"}
      },
      "update": {
        "strokeOpacity": {"signal": "signal_show_map_graticule ? 1 : 0"}
      }
    },
    "transform": [
      { "type": "geoshape", "projection": "map_projection" }
    ]
  },

  {
    "type": "shape",
    "from": {"data": "data_geo_usa"},
    "encode": {
      "enter": {
        "strokeWidth": {"value": 0.5},
        "stroke": {"value": "#bbb"},
        "fill": {"value": "#e5e8d3"}
      }
    },
    "transform": [
      { "type": "geoshape", "projection": "map_projection" }
    ]
  }
```

]
}

Answer (score 1):

Change "data" to:

```
"data": [
  {
    "name": "states",
    "url": "data/us-10m.json",
    "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "states"}
  },
```

[View in Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-1dSOYr0Oqv19PleLjHECAkS2IrLManpDiyiSujWNiqs2FBD1DRtuI1WFFEa8aCGtck7kSMJRDikAADM3GQTBzIS5Z8xCsRhy2uBBgYRRpvhJoZnY1d0DIYw1CgeNLkhXwIB2xQEGTQ6npemg3oxdLDBwFpSQEBUYZkZBFAAa0+Y0AbOGAkF+CItrdP6vjkQYJpAZ7BmB96ZOpEF5HM5rFHMps3QRuAAHUYjiPHo3uGF6bYRnzI5soAGJZGFmStpoBM+Zg2Nd3umFPo6n7cZRlZMaeuBCnRzGgrLCtYo0EBot19QtJAVGIE1y5sdCczxrKJtbvJ8RKcyk09NpvHucZlnRkl7c0ESSgBC5yEeZd-n0AFpgo9F8X0NAcOQAFuABDgAAOWRJVme62q+xX-pV04yHV82McuQ2wv18u9eDBUgA)

[image]

Comment: Nice. 

Any idea how to get this working with an albersUSA flat projection instead of mercator? I've had a go but my drag is janky.

Comment: Thanks Roy, but the projection is not good for me. I need same like here https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/geo_layer.html but just with zoom and drag. By default i need US map for the entire width and height of the container

Comment: See my second example: USA map by states or counties in albersUsa projection with zoom and pan. Adjust the plot width, height, zoom scale and clamping extents to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies but I'm not a mapping expert. I have the following where zoom works fine but the drag is a little janky but definitely useable. It would probably take me quite a while to get this any better.

Roy's answer is another option for you.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "autosize": "none",
  "background": "white",
  "padding": 5,
  "width": 500,
  "height": 300,
  "signals": [
    {"name": "tx", "update": "width / 2"},
    {"name": "ty", "update": "height / 2"},
    {
      "name": "scale",
      "value": 685,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {"type": "wheel", "consume": true},
          "update": "clamp(scale * pow(1.0005, -event.deltaY * pow(16, event.deltaMode)), 150, 3000)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "angles",
      "value": [222, 146],
      "on": [{"events": "mousedown", "update": "[rotateX, centerY]"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "cloned",
      "value": null,
      "on": [{"events": "mousedown", "update": "copy('projection')"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "start",
      "value": null,
      "on": [{"events": "mousedown", "update": "invert(cloned, xy())"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "drag",
      "value": null,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "[mousedown, window:mouseup] > window:mousemove",
          "update": "invert(cloned, xy())"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "delta",
      "value": null,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {"signal": "drag"},
          "update": "[(drag[0] - start[0])*4, (start[1] - drag[1])*4]"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "rotateX",
      "value": 250,
      "on": [{"events": {"signal": "delta"}, "update": "angles[0] + delta[0]"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "centerY",
      "value": 140,
      "on": [{"events": {"signal": "delta"}, "update": "angles[1] + delta[1]"}]
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "source_0",
      "url": "data/us-10m.json",
      "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "states"}
    }
  ],
  "projections": [
    {
      "name": "projection",
      "scale": {"signal": "scale"},
  
      "translate": [{"signal": "rotateX"}, {"signal": "centerY"}],
      "type": "albersUsa"
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "marks",
      "type": "shape",
      "style": ["geoshape"],
      "from": {"data": "source_0"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {"fill": {"value": "lightgray"}, "stroke": {"value": "white"}}
      },
      "transform": [{"type": "geoshape", "projection": "projection"}]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks David. But here is the same as Roy did, USA map is not in focus. You know, i am looking for the same map vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/geo_layer.html  but with drag and zoom. I assume i need to start looking for another library :(

Comment: I think your editor was caching Roy's solution. This one is completely different so you might want to try it again.

Comment: This is what i see by default https://ibb.co/vZ3zLFB. I have to first center the map with the mouse so that it becomes the center of the container.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I can easily change the initial scaling and centre point if this solves your problem. Have a play with zoom and drag to see if it does what you want though.

Comment: That would be great for me, David!